The query string "accountName" is missing or invalid error on two way trust domain
This is about SharePoint 2016 on premise. I have a site running on DomainA. When I open the following URL then it works fine.
https://somesite.domaina.com/sites/somesite/en/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getpropertiesfor(@v)?@v=%27i%3A0%23.w%7Cdomaina%5Csomeuser%27&%22%22

This site has been migrated to another SharePoint 2016 which is running on DomainB. Two way trust is enabled between DomainA and DomainB. So now new site is running from DomainB but users are still accessing from DomainA.
User Profile Service is configured on DomainB SharePoint and is getting data from DomainA. People Picker is also set to only get users from DomainA. Now when I try to open following URL, it throws error.
https://somesite.domainb.com/sites/somesite/en/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getpropertiesfor(@v)?@v=%27i%3A0%23.w%7Cdomainb%5Csomeuser%27&%22%22

Error
The query string "accountName" is missing or invalid.
How do I fix this issue?
